# is ok to choose AWS HTTP API gateway for a mobile application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-http-api, aws-rest-api

I am trying to decide which aws apigateway version choose for my application (HTTP vs REST API gateway).

I am experimenting with AWS HTTP API gateway to see if it works fine for my use case.

These are my requirements:

1. The only client is a mobile application
2. The rest API can be accessed only from logged in users
3. I want to use cognito with cognito authorizer
4. My backend is a mix of lambda services and HTTP rest services exposed via an internal application load balancer

Everything seems to be supported, the only concern is that I would have used an api key, but this feature is not currently supported on HTTP API gateway.

Are there any security concern if I go for HTTP without any api key?
What would be the right way to restrict the access only to requests coming from my mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

> Everything seems to be supported, the only concern is that I would have used an api key, but this feature is not currently supported on HTTP API gateway.

HTTP APIs support OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 authorization
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api.html

If you have any custom api-key, you can still have [an authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html) lambda to authenticate and authorize the client.

> Are there any security concern if I go for HTTP without any api key?

What do you mean by the api-key? API-key is usually static shared secret used mostly in the backend application. Claiming the users need to be authenticated and using the mobile app, having a hardcoded api-key is not the best idea (read - it is a terrible idea)

Under these requirements the default option is using OAuth2/OIDC for user authorization and passing the user's access token along the API requests.

> What would be the right way to restrict the access only to requests coming from my mobile app?

`I want to use cognito with cognito authorizer`

The simplest and built-in way is using the access token from Cognito and built-in JWT API authorizer. Yet you may configure any other option.